# SQL Server 2008: database restore problem with files

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms, backup, restore

We have full backup each Sunday, each evening differential backup and during day transaction log backup.

Now (Tuesday) I want to restore the testing database to state of this afternoon, but I cannot choose full backup, yesterday differential backup and some transaction log from today - see in picture - there is missing the name of files (of full and diff. backup).

But if I choose "to a point in time" option, there are names of full, diff and transaction log backup, but for one (the same time each day) not and restore is not correct.

Please, where is the problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I not forgot, it's cannot to restore DB from a full backup from within "From Database" option. To get access to the full backup file, you should to choose "From device" option, then need to point on at full backup file, **THEN GO TO THE OPTIONS PANE**, choose an "RESTORE WITH NORECOVERY" option, and restore this . It's ok, you has restored DB but it not in operational state - then you need continue restoring DB with differential backup with "RESTORE WITH NORECOVERY" option. And after this you should to restore DB from transactiona buckup files, one by one ordering them by the time (ascend)

Comment: I make this about a year ago, may be incorrect in details by rigth in general, so the better way is to check the upper comment  with the [microsoft arcticle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-a-transaction-log-backup-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Really there is not possible how to choose all of necessary backups (full &diff & transaction log) in one step?

Comment: There is most likehood that no. Anyway, when I practiced restoring of a DB from the three types of buckups, I has doing this step after step (in graphical interface). By the way, nobody to oppose to you to type three restoring T-SQL queries one after another for this buckups (in one SQL-batch). Then you may run this batch and this will restore those bckps into your DB at one action.